# Can a Managed Package with Platform Events work in a Professional Edition Org

Tags: managed-package, platform-event, professional-edition

If we had a `Managed Package` included `Platform Events` would it work in a `Professional Edition` org?

The reason I ask, is that `Platform Events` are not supported in `Pro`, but `Managed Packaged` have their own set of governor limits.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it and the installation of the package fails. This is expected as the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_considerations.htm) states:

*Platform events aren’t supported in Professional and Group Edition orgs. Installation of a package that contains platform event objects fails in those orgs.*